# Where is the address bar and other controls in the "browser" app? (Ubuntu Touch browser)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I can't seem to open the address bar or find the settings button. just trying to access my router so I can fiddle with settings. my router doesn't like chrome.

Comment: Swipe up from the bottom of the window with your mouse. give me a minute and I'll give an illustration.

Comment: thank you that worked. but the ubuntu browser doesn't work right with my router. none of the drop downs work. I used to have to log windows and use IE to access my router

Comment: Try firefox. `sudo apt-get install firefox`. I'll add an answer to this question addressing the Ubuntu browser in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ubuntu browser" is actually the default browser on Ubuntu Touch. It was included in 14.04 Trusty to take over running the webapps versus just opening a new tab in Firefox. The reason it didn't load your router's configuration page any better than Chrome did is because it actually uses the same rendering engine as Chrome (or, more correctly, Chromium) does. I suggest you try using Firefox instead (it should actually be preinstalled).

Anyway, menus and such are hidden by default in Ubuntu Touch; to access them you need to swipe up from the bottom with your finger (or in this case, your mouse).

To access the URL/menu bar bring your mouse down to the bottom of the window, click (and hold) then drag up. The menu should appear.

[image]

(tips go to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for pointing out the browser's intended use in the comments below)

Comment: The "why" could be that it is used to run the web apps.

Comment: @muru Is that an opinion or a statement? Do you have sources? Webapps existed before Ubuntu Touch, so I am somewhat sceptical.

Comment: A statement. I went about looking for more info on Oxide some weeks ago, so I don't recall all the sources. Webapps existed before them, but now they are all using Oxide. See, for example, the [blog post](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=196) announcing it: "The plan is to have the Ubuntu Touch browser and SDK using this by Ubuntu 14.04." and [this Discourse discussion](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/theres-a-ubuntu-browser-in-trusty/1594).